# Writing out results with function in.txt document when there's min and max?

Tags: python, max, min, function

I need a program that would read information from a .txt file, which contains a person's name and his/her age. The trick is that there can be any amount of names and ages, but they also can repeat but count as one person.

The program needs to write the youngest, then the oldest person in a new .txt document.

The .txt it needs to read from looks like this:

```
Sarah 18
Joshua 17
Michael 38
Tom 18
Sarah 18
Michael 38
```

Then after the program is done with the names it should write into a new .txt file like this:

```
Joshua 17
Michael 38
```

So far, I have this:

```
def parse_info():
    info = open("info.txt", "r")
    max_age = 0
    max_name = ''
    min_age = float('inf')
    min_name = ''

    for line in info:
        m_list = line.split(" ") 
        if int(m_list[1]) > max_age:
            max_age = int(m_list[1])
            max_name = m_list[0]
        elif int(m_list[1]) < min_age:
            min_age = int(m_list[1])
            min_name = m_list[0]

    info.close()
```

I'm not sure how to make the program create a new .txt and write the youngest and oldest. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [write() method](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects)  of file objects to write strings into the file

```
with open("new.txt", "w") as output_file:

    output_file.write( "{0} {1}\n".format(max_name, max_age) )
    output_file.write( "{0} {1}".format(min_name, min_age) )
```

Comment: though whenever I try this, to output_file it says "invalid syntax"

Comment: @Hyun Sorry There was a typo. Missed `)` in both statements. Corrected in answer. Hope its working now

Comment: Ah, how could I not see that? Silly me. It appears to be broken but now I have an erroring popping up for my own program saying that`max_name is not defined`. Any suggestions on how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

```
def parse_info():
 info = open("info.txt", "r")
 max_age = 0
 max_name = ''
 min_age = float('inf')
 min_name = ''

 for line in info:
    m_list = line.split(" ")
    if int(m_list[1]) > max_age:
        max_age = int(m_list[1])
        max_name = m_list[0]
    elif int(m_list[1]) < min_age:
        min_age = int(m_list[1])
        min_name = m_list[0]
 info.close()
 return ((min_name,min_age),(max_name,max_age))
 #end of function
nameAge=parse_info()
f = open("output.txt","w")
f.write(nameAge[0][0]+" "+str(nameAge[0][1])+"\n")
f.write(nameAge[1][0]+" "+str(nameAge[1][1]))
```

that should work

Comment: No errors or anything but when it creates a new file it does not write anything into it.

Comment: no it writes to it, i've already tested,make sure you have the info.txt file in the same directory

Answer (score 0):

You can very easily let Python do all the hard work by combining the properties of a set with the properties of how a list of tuples is sorted.

```
def parse_info():
    persons = set()
    for line in open('info.txt'):
        name, age = line.split()
        persons.add((int(age), name))   # Note that age comes first

    # At this point, we have removed all duplicates, now we need
    # to extract the minimum and maximum ages; we can simply do
    # this by converting the set to a list and then sort the list.
    # If a list entry is a tuple, the default behaviour is that it
    # sorts by the first entry in the tuple.
    persons = sorted(list(persons))

    # Now write the data to a new file
    fd = open('new_info.txt', 'w')
    age, name = persons[0]
    fd.write('Youngest: %s %d\n' % (name, age))
    age, name = persons[-1]
    fd.write('Oldest: %s %d\n' % (name, age))
```

parse_info()